# Kids with superpowers, antagonists with metallic eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a short YA series of books about a number of kids with superpowers. Each book focuses on one kid, who at the end meets the other surviving kids and joins them. They are all on the run from a race of supernatural beings, possibly aliens. The mood of the series was somewhat dark, and some of the kids may have died throughout the series.

The most memorable thing I remember was that the antagonists wear sunglasses hiding eyes that seem like dark metallic tunnels, but they otherwise look like normal people. The superpowered kids all had golden blood as well, if I remember correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Silver blood, actually, if I'm right.

*Mindwarp* by Chris Archer is 10 books long.  [Here's the series on GoodReads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/series/61016-mindwarp).  Neither the series nor the author appear to be on Wikipedia.

Summary for the first book, *[Alien Terror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21021.Alien_Terror)*:

> As the legend goes, an alien landed in the cornfields of Metier, Wisconsin. After a short while most of the aliens left. But others assimilated and cross-bred with humans. These children have lived ordinary lives--until now. At age 13, these offspring will manifest their alien powers . . . and have been targeted for termination. In "Alien Terror", Ethan Rogers used to be a wimp. But suddenly he knows martial arts, wrestling moves, combat skills and even weaponry. He'd think it was pretty cool--if he wasn't running for his life.

Here's two of the more distinctive covers, from that page.  All the silver-colored parts are done in foil:

[image: Book 2, Alien Blood][image: Book 9, Out of Time]

(And bleh, these images are extremely low-quality and with bad color depth...)